# iOS simulator for Unity project not running

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator, build-process

I can choose only "My Mac", no simulators available to choose for run. I'm sure I have simulators installed and working.

Build Settings:

```
Architectures: i386
Base SDK: iphonesimulator (SDK not found)
Supported Platforms: iphonesimulator
Valid Archutectures i386 x86_64
```

In Unity I chose `Simulator SDK`. I'm running OS X El Capitan with Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can config Build Settings:

1. Change "Base SDK" to "Latest iOS"
2. Change "Supported Platforms" to "iOS"
3. Change "Architectures" to "Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64).."

This works for me.